# Select statement not working on column name with possible preserved word

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a database filled with information on different columns and am trying some stuff out but started with just doing simple select all statements where a condition is true, such as:
'SELECT * FROM files WHERE ID = 2;'

my table name is called files and one of the columns is called ID which works fine. However, when working with my my column name called 'File', it doesn't work properly and I notice that it is blue like the other preserved words 'SELECT, FROM, and WHERE', so doing something like:
SELECT * FROM files WHERE File = 'example'; doesn't work even if example does exist in there, it just returns a blank result.

Is there a way that I can say that 'File' is a column and should be treated like one without having to re-name it to something else?

[image]

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: do `\`file\` = 'example'`

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Classes these as Reserved Words you can read more here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

To escape these words place `'` around the word:

```
SELECT * FROM file WHERE `file` = 'example';
```